# Unable to check the value of an environmental variable against a string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

EDIT: I run this npm script to start the application and set the `NODE_ENV`:

```
set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon
```

I want to check if the environmental variable `NODE_ENV` equals either 'development' or 'production'. I believe the `console.log()`s below should sufficiently demonstrate my dilemma.

This makes no sense to me, any help would be much appreciated.

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if(NODE_ENV === 'development') // I am struggling to understand why
  console.log('TRUE!!');       // this condition evaluates to false


// LOGS: FALSE
console.log(NODE_ENV === 'development');

// LOGS: FALSE
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development');

// LOGS: development
console.log(NODE_ENV);

// LOGS: string
console.log(typeof NODE_ENV);

// LOGS: string
console.log(typeof process.env.NODE_ENV);

// LOGS: TRUE
console.log(NODE_ENV === process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Comment: Does `process.env.NODE_ENV` contain any spaces or anything? What is `NODE_ENV.length`?

Comment: `NODE_ENV.length` equals 12. Strange...

Comment: If there is an "invisible" (non-printing or whitespace) character in the string you can figure out which character with something like `console.log([].map.call(NODE_ENV,c=>c.charCodeAt(0)))`.

Comment: `NODE_ENV.charCodeAt(12)` logs NaN

Comment: The last character's index is `11`, not `12` (first character's index is `0`).

Comment: Ha, thanks. Dumb mistake. This is the character code for each char:
 
0: 100
 1: 101
 2: 118
 3: 101
 4: 108
 5: 111
 6: 112
 7: 109
 8: 101
 9: 110
10: 116
11: 32

Comment: Well from your edit there is a space character (32) between the "t" and the "&&".

Comment: So, I used `trim()` to fix this, unless you have a better solution? Also, thank you for helping me solve this, if you want to post an answer I can credit you.

Comment: When string comparisons don't seem to match like you expect them to, it's often useful to output the string to the console (or look at it in the debugger) in a delineated fashion as in `console.log("'" + NODE_ENV + "'");` so you can see if there are any extra characters on either end of the string.